# BB Marionette: best way to update a collection without re-rendering

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a very simple page that shows a collection in a table. Above it theres a search field where the user enters the first name of users.

When the user types I want to filter the list down.

Edit: I have updated the code to show how the current compositeView works. My aim is to integrate a searchView that can _.filter the collection and hopefully just update the collection table.

```
define([
  'marionette',
  'text!app/views/templates/user/list.html',
  'app/collections/users',
  'app/views/user/row'
],
  function (Marionette, Template, Users, User) {
    "use strict"

    return Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
      template: Template,
      itemView: User,
      itemViewContainer: "tbody",
      initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new Users()
        this.collection.fetch()
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: Why don't you move out the `#search-users-entry` from your template, so it does not gets rerendered?

Comment: Sound advice, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your template in a few small templates, this increases performance at the client side, you don't have problems with overriden form elements and you have more reuseable code.

But be aware of too much separation, cause more templates means more views and more code/logic.

Comment: So I'd add a listener on a searchUsersView?

Comment: Yes, create searchUsersView as a children of usersView and pass an event method to searchUsersView which is triggered when the form is changed.

Comment: Would you suggest a re-usable searchView?

Comment: Yes, in my own (backbone only) application I had the same problem and solved it with a child search view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be making use of `CollectionView` as well as you could be. If I were you I would separate the concerns between the search box and the search results. Have them as separate views so that when one needs to rerender, it doesn't effect the other.

This code probably won't work straight away as I haven't tested it. But hopefully it gives you some clue as to what `ItemView`, `CollectionView`, and `Layout` are and how they can help you remove some of that boiler plate code

```
//one of these will be rendered out for each search result.
var SearchResult = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#someTemplateRepresentingEachSearchResult"
)};

//This collectionview will render out a SearchResult for every model in it's collection
var SearchResultsView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend{
    itemView: SearchResult
});

//This layout will set everything up
var SearchWindow = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "#someTemplateWithASearchBoxAndEmptyResultsRegionContainer",
    regions:{
        resultsRegion: "#resultsRegion"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.foundUsers = new Users();
        this.allUsers = new Users();
        this.allUsers.fetch({
            //snip...
        });
    events: {
        'keyup #search-users-entry': 'onSearchUsers'
    },
    onSearchUsers: function(e){
        var searchTerm = ($(e.currentTarget).val()).toLowerCase()

        var results = this.allUsers.filter(function(user){
            var firstName = user.attributes.firstname.toLowerCase();
            return firstName.match(new RegExp(searchTerm))
        });

        this.foundUsers.set(results); //the collectionview will update with the collection
    },
    onRender: function(){
        this.resultsRegion.show(new SearchResultsView({
            collection: this.foundUsers
        });
    }
});
```

I think the most important thing for you to take note of is how `CollectionView` leverages the `Backbone.Collection` that you provide it. `CollectionView` will render out an itemView (of the class/type you give it) for each model that is in it's collection. If the `Collection` changes then the `CollectionView` will also change. You will notice that in the method `onSearchUsers` all you need to do is update that collection (using `set`). The `CollectionView` will be listening to that collection and update itself accordingly

Comment: I don't agree with using a layout for this. I already have a layout for the page layout which has sidebar/global search/content area. I was under the impression that a compositeView would allow me to pull in many views and allow for collections to be re-active

Comment: Youre very right in saying that a `layout` is not necessary. I just used a layout to demonstrate a pattern that I thought would be most suitable for what you wanted.

I think the filtering of the searched items and the search bar itself should be a separate concern to the actual displaying of the results. This is what I was trying to demonstrate in my layout. I created a `collection` of users that I passed to the `SearchResultView`. By then updating that collection from somewhere else (that also knew of the search term), the collection would be reactive and update accordingly